# Nodemailer does not work with Aruba Webmail

Tags: node.js, ssl, smtp, tls1.2, nodemailer

I would connect nodemailer to Aruba Webmail. I've tried this

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtps.aruba.it",
  logger: true,
  secure: true,  
  port: 465,
  auth: {
    user: "****",
    pass: "****"
  },
  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    minVersion: 'TLSv1'
  }
})
```

but return this error

```
[2020-03-11 17:15:33] DEBUG Sending mail using SMTP/6.4.4[client:6.4.4]
[2020-03-11 17:15:33] DEBUG [aYJ1bl26Zc] Resolved smtps.aruba.it as 62.149.128.218 [cache miss]
[2020-03-11 17:15:33] ERROR [aYJ1bl26Zc] 140671405623168:error:141A318A:SSL routines:tls_process_ske_dhe:dh key too small:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:2150:
[2020-03-11 17:15:33] ERROR [aYJ1bl26Zc] 
[2020-03-11 17:15:33] DEBUG [aYJ1bl26Zc] Closing connection to the server using "destroy"
[2020-03-11 17:15:33] ERROR Send Error: 140671405623168:error:141A318A:SSL routines:tls_process_ske_dhe:dh key too small:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:2150:
[2020-03-11 17:15:33] ERROR 
[Error: 140671405623168:error:141A318A:SSL routines:tls_process_ske_dhe:dh key too small:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:2150:
] {
  library: 'SSL routines',
  function: 'tls_process_ske_dhe',
  reason: 'dh key too small',
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  command: 'CONN'
}
```

I've also tried without the minVersion, but it return the same error, only the function field change in `ssl_choose_client_version` and the reason field in `unsupported protocol`.

How can i resolve this issue?

**Update:**
I changed my code with this

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp.mydomain.it",
  logger: true,
  secure: false,
  port: 587,
  auth: {
    user: "******",
    pass: "******"
  },
  tls: {
    minVersion: 'TLSv1.2',
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
})
```

Now, thanks to this change, nodemailer can establish a connection, but the error doesn't disappear.
This is the log

```
[2020-03-13 17:35:41] DEBUG Sending mail using SMTP/6.4.4[client:6.4.4]
[2020-03-13 17:35:41] DEBUG [neeofoVybVs] Resolved smtp.mydomain.it as 62.149.128.200 [cache miss]
[2020-03-13 17:35:41] INFO  [neeofoVybVs] Connection established to 62.149.128.200:587
[2020-03-13 17:35:41] ERROR [neeofoVybVs] 140658187040640:error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/statem/statem_lib.c:1929:
[2020-03-13 17:35:41] ERROR [neeofoVybVs] 
[2020-03-13 17:35:41] DEBUG [neeofoVybVs] Closing connection to the server using "end"
[2020-03-13 17:35:41] ERROR Send Error: 140658187040640:error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/statem/statem_lib.c:1929:
[2020-03-13 17:35:41] ERROR 
[Error: 140658187040640:error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/statem/statem_lib.c:1929:
] {
  library: 'SSL routines',
  function: 'ssl_choose_client_version',
  reason: 'unsupported protocol',
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  command: 'CONN'
}
[2020-03-13 17:35:41] INFO  [neeofoVybVs] Connection closed
[2020-03-13 17:35:41] INFO  [neeofoVybVs] Connection closed
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've solved changing my code to this.

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtps.aruba.it",
  logger: true,
  debug:true,
  secure: true,
  port:465,
  auth: {
    user: "*****",
    pass: "*****" 
  },
  tls:{
    minVersion: 'TLSv1',
    ciphers:'HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!eNULL:@STRENGTH:!DH:!kEDH'
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you! I was stuck with this problem and you are the only effective solution that I could find online!

Comment: Thanks :) You saved me time :)

Comment: Any guess with the PEC version ? 

I'm currently facing this error:  {"code":"EENVELOPE","response":"550 5.7.1 Indirizzo IP bloccato temporaneamente per sospetto abuso. Contattare assistenza e utilizzare la Webmail","responseCode":550,"command":"MAIL FROM"}